# Where to point the Messaging endpoint in a bot configuration not on localhost

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I went through [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msteams-messaging-extensions/3-exercise-action-commands) to build my first bot (planetBot). Since I have access to AWS I built it on an EC2 instance (Ubuntu 20) that is accessible on the web. I installed apache on it as well as an SSL certificate so I am `HTTPS`. I have a fully qualified domain and for now, all ports are open.

In the tutorial, most examples use `ngrok` for those who have built their bot on a `locahost` which I have not.

Where I am a little confused is that when using `ngrok` it says to start it in the root project directory. This is where I am not sure if I start it in the entire root project folder `/learn-msteams-msgext` or `/learn-msteams-msgext/src/server/plantBot` where the bot folder is.

Then since I do not need to use `ngrok` and I have my own domain where exactly do I point the Messaging Endpoint to. For instance I built the root folder of my project `https://test.example.com/learn-msteams-msgext` so essentially I put the project folder in `/var/www/html/`

The path to my `bot` within my project is `/var/www/html/learn-msteams-msgext/src/server/planetBot`.

When ever I install my package.zip app in Teams and add it when the bot starts it says `Unable to reach app. Please try again.` So I am suspecting I do not have my Message Endpoint pointing in the right direction in Azure bot configuration.

Did I do this completely wrong? lol, Any help or insights would be great.

**MANIFEST.JSON**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.8/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.8",
  "id": "**********",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "packageName": "planetBot",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Contoso",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.example.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.example.com/privacypolicy/",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.example.com/terms/"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "Planet Messaging",
    "full": "Planet Messaging"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "TODO: add short description here",
    "full": "TODO: add full description here"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "icon-outline.png",
    "color": "icon-color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#D85028",
  "configurableTabs": [],
  "staticTabs": [],
  "bots": [],
  "connectors": [],
  "composeExtensions": [
  {
    "botId": "**********",
    "canUpdateConfiguration": false,
    "commands": [
      {
        "id": "planetExpanderAction",
        "type": "action",
        "title": "Planet Expander",
        "description": "Lookup the details of a planet.",
        "context": [
          "compose",
          "message"
        ],
        "fetchTask": true
      }
    ]
  }
],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "example.com"
  ],
  "showLoadingIndicator": false
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

So in looking at my configurations I realized that in the tutorial the endpoint for `ngrok` adds `/api/messages` from my understanding this is just an `ngrok` thing. Since I am not using `ngrok` and I am exposable on the web I need to edit this. so I changed my endpoint to `https://test.example.com/learn-msteams-msgext` and changed the post path to  `/src/server/planetBot`. Unfortunately, this still did not work.

```
// run the bot when messages are received on the specified path
const bot = new PlanetBot();
express.post("/src/server/planetBot", (request, response) => {
  botAdapter.processActivity(request, response, async (context) => {
    await bot.run(context);
  });
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

Just to clarify when I use `ngrok` to run my bot it works fine. I am trying to use my own URL is where I am having the issue.

Still stuck but learned more. For one I did not realize that I still have to run `gulp` in order for the bot to be able to listen to incoming requests. Since I am not using `ngrok` to get a URL and using my own URL I am running `gulp serve` instead of `gulp ngrok-serve`. The issue I am having now is that if I run the bot with `ngrok` and I navigate to the temporary URL I get from `ngrok` I can reach the bot fine with `https`. If I run the bot with just `gulp serve` (without ngrok) and I navigate to my URL the connection is considered insecure. I am trying to figure out how `ngrok` gets to my box with port `3007` yet remain secure. That is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 2):

So '/api/messages' is actually just a convention with bots. It's not -required-, but -if- you have it -running- that way, you need to configure your Azure bot configuration to -point- to it. In your case it sounds like it's not in use because you've changed this line (from the sample):

`express.post("/api/messages", (request, response) => {`

I would suggest setting it back to the above, and using the convention. Your bot endpoint would then be something like:

`https://www.whateveryourdomainis.com/api/messages`

In that case, you would then deploy the contents of `/learn-msteams-msgext/src/server` which would be the "base" location of the server

Comment: This is where I am confused then. Besides running the web server is there something I have to do to "launch" the bot on my server?

Comment: Do I have to run the root of Apache as `/var/www/html/learn-msteams-msgext/src/server`?

Comment: For instance: If I run `ngrok` andI head over to my url endpoint `https://823fd4f1a91a.ngrok.io/api/messages` I will get `Cannot GET /api/messages` which I get why it would throw that error but that URL is listening to the incoming request. If I use my own URL `https://www.whateveryourdomainis.com/api/messages` and not use `ngrok` I just get a `404` ... and by the way my bot works fine with `ngrok`

Comment: The reason ngrok is failing is because of where you've set as the starting/entry point for your app, and then the address / path it's set to listen on - you've set it to '"/src/server/planetBot"' instead of '/api/messages'

Comment: "Do I have to run the root of Apache as /var/www/html/learn-msteams-msgext/src/server?" - yes, exactly

Comment: Thanks for the help man, I have more updates to my issue. Do you mind reading my second update `(UPDATE 2)`

Comment: sorry for the delay, been a very hectic week. So, with Update 2 you're kind of combining 2 questions in here - one about the local dev environment, one about live web hosting - hoping we can get it all figured out. To answer one point - yes, you need both ngrok AND gulp when running locally. The first (gulp) is for actually -running- your code in a local environment - your machine is basically acting as a web server.

Comment: The 2nd command (i.e. ngrok) is for creating a *tunnel* to the internet so that services, like Teams, can pretend to make an "httpS://something.somewhere.com" call, because "http://localhost" is not secure.

Comment: the 3rd piece in the puzzle though is what endpoing *inside* the web server must get hit. You could, for instance, run web pages AND a bot inside the same app, so you need to tell the app which address to listen on for BOT calls versus say webpage calls. That's what the "/api/messages" is doing.

Comment: So you might have, for example, httpS://something.somewhere.com/Homepage and httpS://something.somewhere.com/api/messages both running in your physical web app

Comment: and to be clear, in this case, httpS://something.somewhere.com is pointing at the base location of the website itself, on your local file system, which I guess is /learn-msteams-msgext/src/server/planetBot

Comment: lots of info, hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, where I am stuck is how to tunnel the app without using ngrok

Comment: Is it possible to use browserSync for this? I tried tons of configs in my gulpfile.ja with no luck